# Block or fade images in Firefox according to their content

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

In **Firefox**, I'm looking for a way to:

1. fade, or add a certain amount of transparency to all images, with the possibility to temporary disable this when I hover the image with the mouse pointer
2. forget images according to a hash of their content and display a nice (transparent?) placeholder instead.

Comment: you may consider using [adblock](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/) but it doesn't fit exactly to your needs

Comment: I was going to recommend adblock as well, but it doesn't do at all what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you able to use jQuery at all. If so you can do a global select

```
$(function(){
    $('.classSelector').not('.omittedClasses').each(function(){
        $(this).fadeTo(100, 0.2).mouseenter(function() { $(this).fadeTo(100, 1) }).mouseleave(function() { $(this).fadeTo(100, 0.2) });
    });
});​
```

Have a look at this working example http://jsfiddle.net/WFvZn/

Comment: Then I guess applying this script, with the good selector to every page in Firefox, is a job for Greasemonkey ?

Comment: There is  a zero width space in your code: Octal Escape Sequence \342\200\213, see http://graphemica.com/200B. Do you know where it's coming from ?